# View Container not showing table view control ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitableview

I'm trying to embed a table view control inside a container here's my app:
when i set the table view control class to UITableViewController every thing works fine:
it shows the controller inside the container.

But now i want to put some code behind the table view controller so i add a class (h,m files)
and set the class of the UITableViewController  to be TableController (thats my class name)
when i load the app now, it doesnt show the controller.

looking for some explanations or solutions to this problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a View controller class instead of creating a tableviewcontroller class . In its xib , add a tablview. Set table's delegates and data source , and start working on it .

Comment: But that won't work becuase i need static table not a dynamic one and i am using storyboard so please if you have a diffrent answer the suits my project i'll be more than thankful

Comment: Yes It'll create static table only . first of all clear your concept about tableview in VC. 
e.g. if you want to list only few cities in a tableview , make an array of those cities. Then accordingly fill the table from the array.